# Can I mention the names of three professors in my Statement of Purpose even if I don't get any response from them?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am going to apply to the US universities for the fall, 2022 for PhD. I have decided to include the names and research interests of three professors in my SOP with whom I would like to work, if I get admitted to their university. I have tried to contact them but haven't got any response. Therefore, I don't know whether they have any funding to take new graduate students in their labs in the fall, 2022 or not.

So, my question is, if I mention their names in my SOP as a prospective student, will it harm my chance of getting admitted or will it be a wise decision to include their names and research interests in my SOP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Three professors feels like a lot.

Comment: @RamPadmanabhan sorry, I disagree. I think it hits the sweet spot between casting too wide a net that it comes across as indecisive (name-dropping 5-6 profs) and narrowing down too much, which could kill your chances, especially when, as OP's situation here suggests, one does not know if the one or two profs are not interested or not taking students that year.

Comment: The answer to this may be field specific. Mentioning possible advisers in math would be completely natural in this context. But you mention "labs" which suggest you are in another field. It may be best to actually ask someone in your undergrad department (possibly someone writing a rec letter) what the norm is in your field.

Comment: @JoshuaZ actually I am from biological sciences and I will pursue my PhD in either biochemistry or physiology. In my field, what I have heard so far, that the students who apply to the US, are not necessarily required to manage professors. But mentioning the names and their research in the SOP will give some evidence that one has done some homework before applying. Normally, in the US, a professor owns his own lab and research team.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do not want to work with any of the other faculty, there is no downside to identifying the three faculty you want to work with.  If you are rejected because those three faculty do not want you, then you saved some time.

The advantages of demonstrating that you thought out what you wanted will always outweigh the risk of naming the faculty you want to work with.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the regulation, some Univ. must have confirmation by the advisor, since they offer you the position to work. Others are just a `make sure checklist` that proved you did doing some visiting and conversation with faculty.
You might need to contact the office of your department.
If this is just a checklist procedure, then it would be fine you can mention whoever's name on the list.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you haven't understood my question. I am going to apply to a university for PhD, lets say Emory University, now the program where I am going to apply has 5-6 professors with whom I would like to work during my PhD. I have tried to contact them but none of them answered, so I do not know whether they have any funding to take new students. So, can I mention their names in my SOP as a prospective student even if they do not respond?

Comment: Yes, this is just a checklist procedure and the intended university does not require managing professors before application. I just want to put their names in SOP to showcase that I have made some research on their university. Thank you very much btw for your suggestion.

Comment: I think the most important thing is you find the best candidates matching your research interest, and rank them after you interviewed them. In my case, I studied electronic engineering Ph.D. , if my ideal profs didn't accept me(all of them), then I would give up and search for another univ. One of my friends studied bio. Ph.D. , his advisor is just not the candidate on the checklist for the procedure. Last year he finish his degree and continues to stay there as a Postdoc.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are in a field where the PI hires doctoral students directly into their lab, you aren't likely to get a response from anyone prior to admission. This is especially true if you are applying with only a bachelors.

But, in any case, most universities have a requirement that you pass a set of preliminary/qualifying/comprehensive exams before you get very serious about doctoral research. This is to assure that you have a broad knowledge of your general field and may require some advanced coursework to pass them.

Since you haven't gotten a reply, then I'll assume that this is the situation at this university.

I don't think that mentioning three professors is necessarily bad, but it isn't really necessary either. If all of them are in a fairly narrow subfield that interests you, it might be enough just to name that subfield.

However, don't overly focus your SoP on these people, or spend too many words on this particular thing. You want to convey your future goals and plans both for your studies and thereafter. Some specificity is needed for this so that you don't appear to be unfocused.

The advantage of the US system, with admissions handled by committee and advisors chosen rather late, is that you get to meet potential advisors before you make a choice. There is more to consider in choosing an advisor to assure that you find someone who is both compatible and who will also provide the appropriate level of support. You might even be able to take a class with a potential advisor and establish some rapport. If you have to choose only based on their field, it is possible to make a serious mistake.

So, naming three is a bit of overkill, but not bad, as long as you use the available space in the SoP to say *all* that needs to be said.

Answer (score -1):

The statement of purpose should be a succinct statement for specific reasons why you have chosen the institution.

What do you value, specifically, about the University, and how does its resources specifically parallel to your scholarly pursuits.

Mentioning professors in this statement in my opinion would not be appropriate. Instead, it is a statement to “sell yourself, to the institution— tell him why you are better than the other applicant to be admitted.

What **truly exceptional qualities** do you possess to be admitted at the institution specifically.

When preparing the statement for graduate study, universities are specifically **looking for scholars that have the same interests as professors at the University currently has on staf**f

You need the state, why specifically, a specific professor within the department in which you were interested possesses a interest that you wish to pursue scholarly pursuits during your time, and how specifically those pursuits would create significant change or creative findings within that field… that are exceptional.

Comment: Most PhD students are not exceptional.